# Java Spring, find with MongoTemplate and generic type

Tags: java, spring, criteria, spring-data-mongodb, generic-programming

I'm trying to build a query which returns a list of generic objects.

It's my base object:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public class Normalized {

  public static final String J_ID = "id";
  public static final String J_CREATED_AT = "createdAt";
  public static final String J_UPDATED_AT = "udpatedAt";

  @Id
  @Indexed
  @JsonProperty(J_ID)
  private String id;
  @JsonProperty(J_CREATED_AT)
  private Instant createdAt;
  @JsonProperty(J_UPDATED_AT)
  private Instant updatedAt;

}
```

It's my domain object:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Document    
public class NormalizedContent<E extends OriginalContent> extends Normalized {

  public static final String J_SOURCE = "source";
  public static final String J_EXTERNAL_URL = "externalUrl";
  public static final String J_MAIN_TEXT = "mainText";
  public static final String J_ORIGINAL_CONTENT = "originalContent";
  public static final String J_CREATED_DATE = "createdDate";

  @Indexed
  @JsonProperty(J_SOURCE)
  private Sources source;

  @Indexed
  @JsonProperty(J_CREATED_DATE)
  private Instant createdDate;

  @JsonProperty(J_EXTERNAL_URL)
  private String externalUrl;

  @JsonProperty(J_MAIN_TEXT)
  private String mainText;

  @JsonProperty(J_ORIGINAL_CONTENT)
  private E originalContent;
}
```

And it's a simplification of my function:

```java
public Page<NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>> findAllByQueriesAndFilters(
      List<String> queriesId, Pageable pageable) {
    if (queriesId == null || queriesId.isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Queries unspecified");
    }
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where(NormalizedContent.J_QUERY).in(queriesId);
    Query query = new Query(criteria);
    query.with(pageable);
    List<NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>> content =
        mongoTemplate.find(query, NormalizedContent.class);

    Long total = mongoTemplate.count(query, OTBUserpanelUser.class);

    return new PageImpl<NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>>(content, pageable, total);
  }
```

The problem is in the line:

```java
List<NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>> content =
            mongoTemplate.find(query, NormalizedContent.class);
```

Because the content variable is a list of `NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>` and the find method returns a list of `NormalizedContent`.

What can I do in order that the find method returns a list of `NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>`?

Comment: Have you tried to cast `(Class<NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>>) NormalizedContent.class` ?

Comment: @OrestKyrylchuk that is my current solution, but for this, I should map all the elements from the list one by one.
I want that the find method returns this, as if I use `NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>.class`

Comment: So you have next code `List<NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>> content =
            mongoTemplate.find(query, (Class<NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>>) NormalizedContent.class);` yes? Not sure what do you mean one by one

Comment: @OrestKyrylchuk I want something like `List<NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>> content = mongoTemplate.find(query, (Class<NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>>) NormalizedContent.class);`, but it isn't correct. My current code is `List<NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>> content =
        mongoTemplate.find(query, NormalizedContent.class).stream()
            .map(normalizedContent -> (NormalizedContent<OriginalContent>) normalizedContent).collect(Collectors.toList());`. In this solution I should cast one by one all the elements of the list.

Comment: @L. Sanchez so the first option is not working ? What error it throws?

Comment: @OrestKyrylchuk the first option doesn't work. The error is `Cannot cast from Class<NormalizedContent> to Class<NormalizedContent<? extends OriginalContent>>`

Answer (score -2):

```
List<NormalizedContent>   content =
    mongoTemplate.find(query, NormalizedContent.class);
```

While retiring NormalizedContent from content, cast to thethe property which hold the `<? extends OriginalContent>`  type.

Comment: Please have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer to provide more detail. Specifically, it would be helpful if you explained how this solves the problem